# What happens to decimal part of floating point data if we assign it to an int?

Tags: c++

I know that `int` can only store non decimal numbers, but in this case:

```
int n=3.14
```

It will only store `3`, but my question is what will happen to `.14`? Will it be lost in memory, or discarded, or temporarily stored?

Comment: Show example code please.

Comment: The `3.14f` value is converted to an `int` and the result of that conversion is `3`. The `3` and `3.14` are distinct values, the `3.14` isn't transformed. Nothing happens to the `.14`, the original `float` value is not affected.

Comment: I'm not certain, but it reads as if the value `3.14` is being conceptualized in memory as those four explicit characters?  As in, _"When it becomes `3`, where did the other three bytes go?"_

Comment: In the case of a floating point literal being assigned to an `int` it's entirely possible that the compiler discards the .14 while building the program since there's no point to performing the conversion at runtime and there will be no effect on the program's behaviour.

Comment: What happens to the hole in the bagel after the bagel is eaten?

Answer (score 2):

The fractional part of a floating point number is truncated when it is assigned to an integral type.

From the [C++ Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.fpint#1):

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type. [ *Note*: If the destination type is `bool`, see [conv.bool](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.bool).  — *end note* ]

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a floating point value to an integral type, the decimals are truncated.

So in your example

```
int n = 3.14;  // will result in n == 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The fractional part will disappear entirely. You can see this by assigning the integer variable to a float variable then printing the float.Subject to rounding (which is not an issue for small integers) it will print out as 3.00....

Comment: You'd have to jump through hoops to get an integer to print as "3.00"

Answer (score -2):

if you already stored a float as int then the part after the point gets "sliced" it also happens in objects the data that isn't part of the stored type just isn't recorded in that object/variable.

Comment: An interesting comparison, but `float` does not inherit from `int`.

Comment: The analogy between numeric truncation and object slicing is misleading and inappropriate.

Comment: Yeah I know, float and int are differently stored(And they aren't classes) but the principle is similar, the data is ignored/not stored at all and the data is lost, the analogy seemed right to me.

Comment: It's not an altogether bizarre analogy. From a high-level perspective it's indeed a similar thing - additional information being discarded under certain circumstances (notably a type change) - and it's not a stretch to think of floating-point values as an extension of integral values. To reject this because `float` and `int` aren't classes is to miss the point somewhat.